# Can't load all products in Indexcontroller

Tags: product, collection, controllers

I have a simple Indexcontroller.

When I use this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
echo count($collection);
```

It doesn't show all the product (just a few), what could the reason for this be? I would like to load all products, doesn't matter what the status is.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to Alan Storm I found the answer. In using: `echo (string) $collection->getSelect();` I saw: `(_table_name.store_id = 5)`

By setting it to storeId 0 ('admin' so to say) I was able to see all the product.

Sounds logical... as always :-)

Comment: The fact you're loading from a controller shouldn't have anything to do with it. Can you please tell us what Magento version, one or multiple websites/ shopviews, if you're using flat indexes (try and refresh cache and indexes perhaps), what is 'a few' are we talking about 10 out of 1000? Some more info would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's too many reasons to list (or to even know) why your product collection may not be returning all the products you think it should.  It may be a bug, may be an extension you installed, or may be you have a misunderstanding as to what's returned in a default collection.

Fortunately, this is a relatively simple thing to debug yourself.  You can take a peek at the `SELECT` statement used by the collection to populate its initial objects.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 

echo (string) $collection->getSelect();
```

With that SQL in hand, it should be pretty easy to tell why Magento isn't returning the objects you think it should.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! Posted the answer in my main question.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to get the count of items in a collection. Unfortunately the PHP internal `count` function is probably not the most performant way.

Here are two others to try:

```
echo $collection->count();

echo $collection->getSize();
```

What I suspect is happening is either your collection isn't as deep as you think it is; there is a memory issue with the PHP `count` function (iterates the collection as an array); or `count` isn't aware of how many items there actually are [due to lazy loading](http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections), where the collection isn't actually being loaded up at the time you're asking for its count.

Comment: I agree. In your code the PHP count will be initiating the collection->load() functionality, and count may be quitting (for whatever reason) before the complete collection returns from the database.

Try issuing a $collection->load(); first, and see if that makes a difference, and as suggested, rather use the collection->count() thereafter.

Comment: Thanks guys, had to do with my store id, answer is in my main question